# Is there any macOS snipping app can take picture with lower resolution

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, catalina, ms-office

The native snipping tool in macOS takes an image with the full original pixel.
when I paste it to use, the resolution is a little too big to web blog or in Microsoft-word, I need to resize it smaller by hand every time, is there any other snipping tool that can take a lower resolution image in clipboard?

Comment: No, but there are plenty of image apps that you could use to automatically create a version at a smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

When you capture a screen (or portion of), the app uses the actual size it captured.  If your window, for example is 600x300, that will be the size of the image.

What you will need to do is save the image to a file instead of having it in the clipboard (yes, there are extra steps).  You can [manually edit the size of the image](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/resize-rotate-or-flip-an-image-prvw2015/mac) In Preview by using the *Adjust Size* function found under the tools menu.

I recommend doing it this way, at least for the first set of images so you can find the optimal size to adjust to.  After that, you can use Automator to create an “application” or a “watched folder” that will do this for you.  Below is a sample Automator app that will resize images in a folder to get you started.

[image]

You can scale (resize) the image by percentage or by actual pixels.  You can then drag that image to whatever application you want to use.